# Geom_vline averaging values across facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app and I am trying to put a vertical line at the mean of the user specified variable by group, where Group B is a subset of Group A. Additionally I want to facet the plot by the year. It worked once but now it is giving me the average of the 2 values and putting that value as the vertical line.

As you can see in the image below, the same vertical line is in both facets, and it is an average of the values for the two years. Here the mean of the variable in 2020 is for group A (in the yellow line) is 2.8 and the mean in 2021 for group A is 2.67. Yet the yellow line in this plot is at ~2.75, which is an average of the two values. Similarly, the mean of the variable in 2020 for group B (which is a subset of Group A and in the purple line) is 2.23 and in 2021 the mean is 1.95, yet the purple line is at ~2.1, which would be about the average of the two values.

[image]

This is the code that I used. And I want a line for each year for each group. I apologize if this is really messy code! I'm still just learning!

```
 output$vargraph <- renderPlot({
    dattest2 <- dattotal %>% filter(SchoolName == input$school) ##choosing Group B
    years <- c(input$Year2, input$Year1)
    dattest2 <- dattest2 %>% filter(Year %in% years)
    variab <- dattotal[, input$Variable]
    variab2 <- dattest2[, input$Variable]
    varb <- as.name(names(dattotal[input$Variable]))
    ggplot(dattest2, aes(!!varb)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = .5, colour = "green", linewidth = 2, fill = "white") + theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(name = paste(input$Variable, "Score"), breaks = seq(0, 5, .25), labels = seq(0, 5, .25)) +
      labs(y = "Frequency") + facet_wrap(~Year) +
      geom_vline(data = filter(dattest2, Year == input$Year1), aes(xintercept = mean(variab2, na.rm = T)), colour="purple", linewidth = 2) + 
      geom_vline(data = filter(dattotal, Year == input$Year1), aes(xintercept = mean(variab, na.rm = T)), colour="yellow",linewidth = 2) +
      geom_vline(data = filter(dattest2, Year == input$Year2), aes(xintercept = mean(variab2, na.rm = T)), colour="purple", linewidth = 2) +
      geom_vline(data = filter(dattotal, Year == input$Year2), aes(xintercept = mean(variab, na.rm = T)), colour="yellow", linewidth = 2) 
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem stems from not quite understanding what's happening in the `geom_vline()` statements.  Any computation set within mapping (`aes()`) doesn't refer back to `data=`.  So, for this:

```
geom_vline(data = filter(dattest2, Year == input$Year1),
  aes(xintercept = mean(variab2, na.rm = T)),
  colour="purple", linewidth = 2)
```

It will create a line in the dataset where `Year == input$Year1`, which is what you want, but the `xintercept` is computing the `mean()` value for `variab2`.  In your code above, that's just pulling out the column within `dattest2` as in `variab2 <- dattest2[, input$Variable]`.  `variab2` therefore contains all values for your `input$Variable` in `dattest2`, and not just those values that correspond to a specific value for `Year`.

One solution to this is to first create a summary dataset that you can use which calculates all your necessary values for `xintercept` you want to use, then you only need one `geom_vline()` command to draw all the proper lines with the right color in the proper dataset.

#### Example Using `iris` Dataset

Here's an example plot from `iris`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white") +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~Species)
p
```

[image]

To draw the intercept lines, first I am summarizing the data in a new dataframe.  First, I'm grouping by `Species` (which is the faceting variable), and summarizing the values of interest: here `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Length`.  Ultimately, we want the data to be arranged by the faceting variable (`Species`), the name we gave to the value calculated, and the value itself.  We can do this via `pivot_longer()`.

```
lines_data <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    intercept_1 = mean(Sepal.Width),
    intercept_2 = mean(Petal.Length)
  ) %>% 
  # we now have Species | intercept_1 | intercept_2
  pivot_longer(
    cols=c("intercept_1", "intercept_2"),
    names_to = "intercept_name", values_to = "intercept_value")
  # now we have Species | intercept_name | intercept_value
```

Then, the new plot is created with a single call to `geom_vline()`.  This also creates a legend, but you can stop that from happening if you use `show.legend=FALSE`.  The term `key_glyph="path"` turns the legend keys (icons) into horizontal lines instead of the default vertical lines because it looks nicer.

```
p + geom_vline(
  data=lines_data, aes(xintercept=intercept_value, color=intercept_name),
  linewidth=1, key_glyph="path")
```

[image]

#### Proposal for OP's code

Based on the above strategy, I would guess something like this might work for you.  I had to kind of reverse engineer the structure of your dataset... so it might not work as intended, but the idea should work overall.  It seemed that `dattotal` was a dataset which included everything, and `dattest2` was created as a filter of that dataset for the specified input years.  You want the purple and yellow lines to correspond to values for the particular Year and school, etc and one to correspond for the "total" (all schools) for a particular year, right?

You'll see that this time, `lines_data` is created separately for both of those datasets, then merged together before "tidying" up using `pivot_longer()`.  Overall, it's the same idea as above applied to the `iris` dataset.

```
output$vargraph <- renderPlot({
  dattest2 <- dattotal %>% filter(SchoolName == input$school) ##choosing Group B
  years <- c(input$Year2, input$Year1)
  dattest2 <- dattest2 %>% filter(Year %in% years)

  # creating the summary dataframe
  lines_data <- dattotal %>% filter(Year %in% years) %>%
    group_by(Year) %>%
    summarize(variab = mean(input$Variable, na.rm = TRUE))
  lines_data2 <- dattest2 %>%
    group_by(Year) %>%
    summarize(variab2 = mean(input$Variable, na.rm = TRUE))
  lines_data <- merge(lines_data, lines_data2, by="Year")  # merge
  lines_data <- lines_data %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols= -Year,   # don't pivot on Year column.  Do for everything else
      names_to = "variable_name", values_to="intercept"
    )
  # should be: Year | variable_name | intercept
  
  # variab <- dattotal[, input$Variable]
  # variab2 <- dattest2[, input$Variable]
  varb <- as.name(names(dattotal[input$Variable]))
  ggplot(dattest2, aes(!!varb)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = .5, colour = "green", linewidth = 2, fill = "white") + theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(name = paste(input$Variable, "Score"), breaks = seq(0, 5, .25), labels = seq(0, 5, .25)) +
    labs(y = "Frequency") + facet_wrap(~Year) +
    geom_vline(
      data=lines_data,
      aes(xintercept=intercept, color=variable_name),
      linewidth=2, key_glyph="path"
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("yellow", "purple"))  # gives you the colors you wanted
})
```